# Append #divId to url in kaminari pageination links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, kaminari

I wan to add #divId to the url in kaminari pagination links so that i can navigate to specific portion of the page. How can I achieve that?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= paginate @something, :params => { :anchor => 'divId' } %>
```